# How to pass a concatenated string as a parameter to function: Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I have the following code:

```
...    
<tr ngFor= "let i = index">
    <myCustomElement myName="{{'nameEdit'+i}}">
        <button 
          <--This is where I get the "Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected" error-->
          (click)="myFunction(requestForm.controls.'nameEdit'{{i}}.value)">
        </button>
    </myCustomElement>
</tr>
...
```

My goal is pass to `myFunction` the value of `nameEdit` for each element (so this will be `nameEdit1`, `nameEdit2`, `nameEdit3` and so on. My existing code results to an *Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected* error.

What's the proper way to pass my value to `myFunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(click)="myFunction(requestForm.controls['nameEdit' + i].value")` should do the trick

Since double quotes for event directives `(...)` are interpolated, the `{{ ... }}` is unnecessary. You will need to also use the javascript object identifier `[...]` with the dynamic text.

Lastly, this will obviously return error if the `controls` doesn't have a key with the name you're trying to parse. It would be best practice to have `myFunction(...)` manage this case.

Working stackblitz example that outputs the values: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whq8ll-od64hx?file=app/slider-overview-example.html